# Automatic generation of composite key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Good morning.
I have a db table with a composite primary key. This is the create statement of the table

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "ACQUISTO_EVENTI"(
"COD_PROPOSTA_EVENTO" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
"COD_PROPOSTA" INTEGER CS_INT,
"ID_EVENTO" INTEGER CS_INT,
"TIPO_OPERAZIONE" VARCHAR(100),
    ... others fields...
PRIMARY KEY (
    "COD_PROPOSTA_EVENTO"
)
```

The composite primary key formula is

```
COD_PROPOSTA_EVENTO = "COD_PROPOSTA" + _ + "ID_EVENTO"
```

To save the data on the db I created the following POJO object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACQUISTO_EVENTI")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PropostaAcquisto implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5977779326596870770L;

    public PropostaAcquisto() {
        super();
    }
    
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "COD_PROPOSTA_EVENTO", length=100)
    private String codPropostaEventoPrimaryKey;
    
    @Column(name = "COD_PROPOSTA")
    private Integer codProposta;        
    
    @Column(name = "ID_EVENTO")
    private Integer idEvento;   
    
    @Column(name = "TIPO_OPERAZIONE", length=100)
    private String tipoOperazione;
    
        ... others fields...

    public Integer getCodProposta() {
        return codProposta;
    }

    public void setCodProposta(Integer codProposta) {
        this.codProposta = codProposta;
    }

    public Integer getIdEvento() {
        return idEvento;
    }

    public void setIdEvento(Integer idEvento) {
        this.idEvento = idEvento;
    }
    
    public String getCodPropostaEventoPrimaryKey() {
        return codProposta + "_" + idEvento;
    }

    public void setCodPropostaEventoPrimaryKey(String codPropostaEventoPrimaryKey) {
        this.codPropostaEventoPrimaryKey = codProposta + "_" + idEvento;
    }
    
    public String getTipoOperazione() {
        return tipoOperazione;
    }

    public void setTipoOperazione(String tipoOperazione) {
        this.tipoOperazione = tipoOperazione;
    }

            ... others getter and setters...
}
```

When I try to save an object with the following code

```
   public Object saveOrUpdate() {
        PropostaAcquisto propostaAcquisto = new PropostaAcquisto();
        propostaAcquisto.setCodProposta(1);
        propostaAcquisto.setIdEvento(1);

        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            if (session == null || ! session.isOpen()) {
                session = HibernateFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            } 
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (JDBCException e) {
            System.out.println("Dettaglio errore >>> "+e.getSQLException().getMessage());
            obj = null;
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            } 
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): PropostaAcquisto
```

There is a way to automatic generete the primary key with Hibernate without to call directly

```
propostaAcquisto.setCodPropostaEventoPrimaryKey()
```

before to save the object?
Someone can provide me some examples or documentation links?
Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Hibernate 5.x**

You can probably use `@PrePersist`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACQUISTO_EVENTI")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PropostaAcquisto implements Serializable {

    @PrePersist
    public void createKey() {
        this.codPropostaEventoPrimaryKey = this.codProposta + "_" + this.eventoId;
    }

}
```

See the Hibernate ORM documentation for more info [about JPA Callbacks](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks).

**For Hibernate ORM 4.3.x**

If you are using an older version of Hibernate ORM, you can probably achieve the same [registering an event listener](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html_single/#registering-listeners-example) on the `EventType.PERSIST`:

```
public class MyIntegrator implements org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator {

    public void integrate(
            Configuration configuration,
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

        final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService( EventListenerRegistry.class );

        // If you wish to have custom determination and handling of "duplicate" listeners, you would have to add an
        // implementation of the org.hibernate.event.service.spi.DuplicationStrategy contract like this
        eventListenerRegistry.addDuplicationStrategy( myDuplicationStrategy );

        // This form adds the specified listener(s) to the beginning of the listener chain
        eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners( EventType.PERSIST, new CreatePKBeforePersist() );
}
```

Where `CreatePKBeforePersist` is a class implementing `PersistEventListener`.

Because you cannot bind the listener to a specific entity, you will have to check the object before applying the change:

```
public class CreatePKBeforePersist implements PersistEventListener {

    public void onPersist(PersistEvent event) throws HibernateException {
        if (event.getObject() instanceof PropostaAcquisto) {
            PropostaAcquisto pa = (PropostaAcquisto) event.getObject();
            pa.createKey();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

[This article explains how you can register an integrator](https://in.relation.to/2012/01/09/event-listener-registration/):

Add a text file in:

```
/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
```

the file will contain only the full name of your class:

```
org.project.MyIntegrator
```

You can check the `java.util.ServiceLoader` JavaDocs for a complete explanation of what's possible to inlcude in the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my project I use an old versione of HIbernate (4.3.5.Final) and I cannot upgrade it and in this old version there is not the @PrePersist annotation. <br> Is there another way to achieve the same results with Hibernate or with java code?

Comment: After the creation of `CreatePKBeforePersist` class how can I bind it to my POJO class to create a primary key? Thanks

Comment: You cannot bind it a single class, you need to check the type of the object before insert: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/ I don't thinkg Hibernate ORM 4 has that kind of mechanism.

Comment: Added an example to the answer